# Zoom Vs. Scale in CSS3

Tags: css, dom, zooming, scale

I was looking for some css properties that I never used and came to know about `zoom` property of **css3**

- What is the similarities and difference between them?
- When to use Zoom and when scale? Both do pretty much the same job.
- Which is more efficient to use and why?

### What have I noticed?

- both scales the object but default transform-origin for scale its center and for zoom its top-left I think;
- when we use them for scaling on hover, zoom will scale and again shrinks to the original dimension, while scale will only shrink on hover-out.
  [-->> jsfiddle showing hover effectst](http://jsfiddle.net/KkpyY/)**

```css
*
{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
 -ms-transition-duration: 0.3s;
 -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
 transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

box, box2
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    
    margin: 20px;
}

box
{
    background: #b00;
}

box:hover
{
    zoom: 1.1;
}

box2
{
    background: #00b;
}

box2:hover
{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
 -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
 -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
 -o-transform: scale(1.1);
 transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<box></box>
<box2></box2>
```

---

### Some Stackoverflow QA

- [What Does 'zoom' do in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278783/what-does-zoom-do-in-css)
- [Zoom versus -transform scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279757/zoom-versus-transform-scale)

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
.one {
  background: #07a;
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  -moz-transform: scale(2);
  -ms-transform: scale(2);
  -o-transform: scale(2);
  transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: top top;
}
.two {
  background: #eee;
  zoom: 200%;
  margin-left:100px;
}

.three {
  background: #07a;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transition:all 0.6s ease;
}

.three:hover{
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  -moz-transform: scale(2);
  -ms-transform: scale(2);
  -o-transform: scale(2);
  transform: scale(2);
}

.four {
  background: #eee;
  transition:all 0.6s ease;
}

.four:hover{
  zoom: 200%;
}
```

```html
<h4>Already zoomed and scalled</h4>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<hr>
<h4>Zoomed and Scalled on hover</h4>
<div class="three"></div>
<div class="four"></div>
```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Transform is more predictable than zoom across browsers.

**Zoom affects *positioning* differently in different browsers.**

example:
`position:absolute; left:50px; zoom: 50%;`

- Chrome will effectively compute the `left` value to `50px * 50%`, that is `25px`...but this is not reflected in DevTools Computed Values.
- IE will not change the `left` value at all.

**Transform is handled the same way in all browsers** (as far as I can tell).

example:
`position:absolute; left:50px; transform: scale(0.5)`

- `left` would effectively be set to `25px` in both Chrome and IE. (DevTools Computed Values will not reflect this - it will display the source code only)
- To avoid changing the `left` value, simply use `transform-origin: 0 0`. That will ensure left is still 50px.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4z728fmk/ shows 2 boxes where the small one is zoomed or scaled to 50%. Looks like this:

[image: comparison of zoom and transform in different browsers]

EDIT: Added Firefox in 2016. At the time it was the most problematic browser out of the three, as `zoom:50%` had no effect at all. And with `transform: scale(0.5)` the borders around the inner box have different thickness... but that could be a subpixel issue

Comment: Thank you somewhat helpful!

Comment: Well Explained about it.

Comment: @Drkawashima do you know which method is better for performance?

Answer (score 16):

Complementary to Drkawashima's answer:

- `zoom` doesn't work in Firefox at all. See [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=zoom)
- *Once upon a time* (fairy tale ends here sorry), `zoom: 1;` was the mighty declaration that helped to debug IE6. It conferred the element it was applied an internal "switch" to this browser named hasLayout (not a CSS property, just a concept like "clearfix" is). You'll find `position: relative; zoom: 1;` quite a lot in old projects

Comment: Nice addition.
I've now updated my answer to include an image showing how FF fails when it comes to zoom

Answer (score 3):

`zoom` does not work with css animations or `transition` propriety:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

Answer (score 3):

`zoom` is not standard css feature.

from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom):

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not
> use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every
> user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
> implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Use `transform: scale(0.8)` instead.

Comment: You may want to use it in conjunction with `transform-origin: 0 0`.

Answer (score 2):

`zoom` and `scale` work quite differently when it comes to layout. While `scale` scales the element as is `zoom` works like a global browser zoom applied to a specific element.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR; Use transform: scale instead of zoom**

I'm compiling all the answers after reading and researching.

```
╔═════════════════════════════╦════════════╦════════════════════════╗
║                             ║ Zoom       ║ Transform Scale        ║
╠═════════════════════════════╬════════════╬════════════════════════╣
║ CSS Animations              ║ No         ║ Yes                    ║
╠═════════════════════════════╬════════════╬════════════════════════╣
║ Cross Browser Compatibility ║ No         ║ Yes                    ║
╠═════════════════════════════╬════════════╬════════════════════════╣
║ Consistent Layout           ║ No         ║ Yes                    ║
╠═════════════════════════════╬════════════╬════════════════════════╣
║ Usage                       ║ zoom: 50%; ║ transform: scale(0.8); ║
║                             ║            ║ transform-origin: 0 0; ║
╚═════════════════════════════╩════════════╩════════════════════════╝
```

References:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63029189/9275249
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom
3. https://caniuse.com/?search=zoom
4. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26712500/9275249