# Scaling a flexbox child with transform leaves empty space

Tags: css, flexbox, css-transforms

I have a flexbox with 5 direct children. The first and last column (.colonnade__column) shall be scaled to zero (instead of `display: none`).
When done, the content scales as expectet, but keeps the space reserved. So the next/previous element will not move.

I tried around with sizing of the child elements of the columns and making the column itself more flexible, but I was running in dead ends…

HTML

```
<div class="colonnade">
    <aside class="sidebar colonnade__column alpha">
        <div class="">
            NAVI
        </div>
    </aside>
    <label class="colonnade__trigger alpha" for="colonnade-alpha">
        <span class="label">
            Show Navigation
        </span>
    </label>
    <main class="main" id="main">
    </main>
    <aside class="sidebar colonnade__column omega">
        <div class="">
            CART
        </div>
    </aside>
    <label class="colonnade__trigger omega" for="colonnade-omega">
        <span class="label">
            Show Cart
        </span>
    </label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.colonnade {
    display: flex;
}

.colonnade__column {
    padding: 1em;
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 16em;
    max-width: 20em;
    /*display: none;*/
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: transform .3s;
    background: #ccc;
}

.colonnade__column.alpha {
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.colonnade__column.omega {
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
}

.colonnade__state.alpha:checked ~ .colonnade__column.alpha,
.colonnade__state.omega:checked ~ .colonnade__column.omega {
    /*display: block;*/
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

Take a look at the codepen. The beheaviour is triggered by the light grey areas with vertical text.

https://codepen.io/bitstarr/pen/WKbMjL

Comment: transform is only a visual effect, it doesn't affect the layout

Comment: Indeed....this is fundamental.

Comment: I was looking for a duplicate that seems to have deasappered, here is the snippet that went along https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/details/jzyBaz/

Comment: Could you not position the one you want to hide absolutely?  Also why can you not use display why hide it using scale, you never explained that?

Comment: The hiding of the outer content should have a nice effect, nothins binary like the display property. Also using absolute positioning the sidebars could overlay the main content, which is sized depending the sidebars in my example.

Comment: you may be looking for `zoom` (worked for me) (seems meant for affect the layout?) (not sure why not used popular) - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488960/zoom-vs-scale-in-css3 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temani's comment is correct: `transform` is only a visual effect, it doesn't affect layout. Layout is computed *before* transforms are applied.

Instead, you can achieve this effect by using flexbox properties:

```
.colonnade {
    display: flex;
}

.colonnade__column {
    flex: 0 1 0; /* Shorthand for: flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis */
    padding: 1em 0; /* Remove left/right padding when columns are hidden */
    transition: all .3s;
    background: #ccc;
}

.colonnade__state.alpha:checked ~ .colonnade__column.alpha,
.colonnade__state.omega:checked ~ .colonnade__column.omega {
    flex: 1 0 20%;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
}
```

Updated demo here: https://codepen.io/wiiiiilllllll/pen/pZvLzj.

Comment: Starting the day with your input really helped. I moved the padding from the column to the child elements, so there is only a toggle on flex properties now. see https://codepen.io/bitstarr/pen/mjJJEw

Comment: This solution cannot contain scaled child. there are scenarios scale is necessary