# Angular Transform Scale - Remove Whitespace

Tags: css, angular

I am working on project where I need to scale down multiple large tables dynamically. I am achieving this by using transform: scale. Here is a simple version of what I am trying to achieve in stackblitz.

[StackBlitz - Scaling Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bkarvangula-teebgl)

The issue is when I scale down there is white space at the bottom. I have text and additional tables after this. How do remove this white space? I know this has been asked before but I am struggling to find a working solution especially for angular.

[image: Table]

**HTML**

```
<h1>Transform</h1>
<button (click)="setScale1(1)">Original</button>
<button (click)="setScale1(0.5)">Scale 50%</button>
<button (click)="setScale1(0.25)">Scale 25%</button>

    <div style="transform-origin:0 0;" [style.transform]="'scale('+scale1+')'">
      <table style="width:130%;background-color:#D3D3D3;">
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th> 
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Sex</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jill</td>
          <td>Smith</td> 
          <td>50</td>
          <td>F</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Eve</td>
          <td>Jackson</td> 
          <td>94</td>
          <td>F</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Toby</td>
          <td>Smith</td> 
          <td>50</td>
          <td>M</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Tom</td>
          <td>Jackson</td> 
          <td>66</td>
          <td>M</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div>I would like this text to be directly after the blue container like when at 100% scale</div>
    <br>
    <button (click)="setScale2(1)">Original</button>
    <button (click)="setScale2(0.5)">Scale 50%</button>
    <button (click)="setScale2(0.25)">Scale 25%</button>
    <div style="transform-origin:0 0;" [style.transform]="'scale('+scale2+')'">
      <table style="width:130%;background-color:#D3D3D3;">
        <tr>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Type</th> 
          <th># Of Employees</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>ABC Company</td>
          <td>Customer</td> 
          <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Other Company</td>
          <td>Customer</td> 
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Delta Force</td>
          <td>Supplier</td> 
          <td>100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Alpha Rig</td>
          <td>Supplier</td> 
          <td>33</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div>I would like this text to be directly after the blue container like when at 100% scale</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { animate, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';
/**
 * @title Expansion panel as accordion
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'expansion-steps-example',
  templateUrl: 'expansion-steps-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['expansion-steps-example.css']
})
export class ExpansionStepsExample {
  scale1: string = '1';
  scale2: string = '1';


  setScale1(value: string): void {
    this.scale1 = value;
  }
  setScale2(value: string): void {
    this.scale2 = value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zoom: 0.3` instead of `scale: 0.3` however that [will affect browsers differently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26712500/794481), and won't work in Firefox.

Another workaround is to [emulate zoom with transform (demo)](https://jsfiddle.net/t5utds44/7). Explained [here](https://medium.com/@sai_prasanna/simulating-css-zoom-with-css3-transform-scale-461d1b9762d6)

[image]

Comment: Thanks buddy, I was previously using zoom to do this but due to firefox incompatibility I moved to transform. I've used the suggested solution to wrap it in a container and dynamically adjust the container's height  when the scale is changed and works like a charm. Updated Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/bkarvangula-cmgzyb

Answer (score 2):

Using the Tallboy's suggested article here is the full solution for anyone interested. The suggested solution is to:

Updated stackblitz [Working Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bkarvangula-cmgzyb)

1. Wrap the table in a container and dynamically adjust the container's height when the scale is changed.
2. I get the height by assigning an id to the table
3. Get the height through document.getElementById
4. Change the height by multiple the height of the container (clientHeight) by the scale factor

[image: Transform]

**HTML**

## Transform

Original
    Scale 25%
    Scale 50%
    Scale 150%
    
    
      
      
        
          
            Firstname
            Lastname 
            Age
            Sex
          
          
            Jill
            Smith 
            50
            F
          
          
            Eve
            Jackson 
            94
            F
          
          
            Toby
            Smith 
            50
            M
          
          
            Tom
            Jackson 
            66
            M
          
        
      
    
    I would like this text to be directly after the table  like when at 100% scale
        
        Original
        Scale 25%
        Scale 50%
    
    
      
      
        
          
            Company
            Type 
            # Of Employees
          
          
            ABC Company
            Customer 
            50
          
          
            Other Company
            Customer 
            4
          
          
            Delta Force
            Supplier 
            100
          
          
            Alpha Rig
            Supplier 
            33
          
        
      
    
    I would like this text to be directly after the table like when at 100% scale

**Javascript**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { animate, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';
/**
 * @title Expansion panel as accordion
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'expansion-steps-example',
  templateUrl: 'expansion-steps-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['expansion-steps-example.css']
})
export class ExpansionStepsExample {
  scale1: string = '1';
  scale2: string = '1';

  height1: number;
  height2: number;


  setScale1(value: string): void {
    this.scale1 = value;
    this.setHeight('table1');   

  }
  setScale2(value: string): void {
    this.scale2 = value;
    this.setHeight('table2');   
  }
  setHeight(id: string): void {
      if (id === 'table1') {
        this.height1 = document.getElementById(id).clientHeight*parseFloat(this.scale1);
      }
      if (id === 'table2') {
        this.height2 = document.getElementById(id).clientHeight*parseFloat(this.scale2);
      }
  }
}
```