# In Javascript how do I set a sites zoom level as indicated in the navigation bar (NOT `body.style.zoom`)?

Tags: javascript, html, zooming, chromium

This is a follow up to my previously asked question about [trackpad based zooming in Chromium based browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76747087/in-javascript-how-to-achive-similar-zoom-in-out-behavior-on-firefox-and-chromiu), but it's a different question.

I want to programmatically set the zoom level in a browser window.
This seems to be a common demand, as some prior (very old though) questions show:

- [imitate browser zoom with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464038/imitate-browser-zoom-with-javascript)
- [Changing the browser zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055336/changing-the-browser-zoom-level)
- [How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers)

However all those questions seem to get answers suggesting to set `body.style.zoom` or `body.style.transform`. But this seems to be a different thing, e.g. the zoom level indicated in the navigation bar does not change, elements are being drawn differently and after a reload these settings are gone.

So - risking down-votes for redundantly asking questions - in 2023 is there a way (at least in Chromium based browsers) to set the *zoom level as indicated in the navigation bar* programmatically (i.e. in JavaScript)?

Comment: Please don’t ask questions that are duplicates except for a sentence that says “Is the answer different now that time has passed?” instead you can [offer a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on the existing question.

Comment: My question is not a duplicate as I pointed out. The OPs of the referenced questions seemed to be ok with just the `body` element to be drawn scaled or they needed to know the scaling. I'm explicitly asking for 'the zoom level as indicated in the navigation bar', which is not touched by the linked questions.

Comment: The accepted answer on the duplicate says “not possible in most browsers” (and then goes on to offer alternatives).